# converting dataframe with label to array in julia

Tags: julia

I have data frame with header in Julia , but I need to convert this to array for some filtering , there is some similar post that people suggest
using :

```
iris[:, 1:3]
```

to get array from dataframe but this method wont work on dataframe with header , any suggestion what should I do ?

dataframe format :

```
FP | C1 | Cz | C2 ....
*  | *  | *  | *  ....
.  | .  | .  | .  ....
.  | .  | .  | .  ....
.  | .  | .  | .  ....
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Have you tried `convert(Matrix, iris[:,1:3])`?
e.g.

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a = 1:4, b = 1:4, c = randn(4), d = randn(4))
4×4 DataFrame
│ Row │ a     │ b     │ c        │ d          │
│     │ Int64 │ Int64 │ Float64  │ Float64    │
├─────┼───────┼───────┼──────────┼────────────┤
│ 1   │ 1     │ 1     │ 1.72172  │ -0.377729  │
│ 2   │ 2     │ 2     │ 0.206415 │ -0.266014  │
│ 3   │ 3     │ 3     │ 1.03785  │ -0.0317582 │
│ 4   │ 4     │ 4     │ 0.632473 │ -0.409014  │

julia> convert(Matrix, df[:,1:3])
4×3 Array{Float64,2}:
 1.0  1.0  1.72172
 2.0  2.0  0.206415
 3.0  3.0  1.03785
 4.0  4.0  0.632473
```

Comment: Perfect! :-) Happy to help. One note: If you have Null / NA values, you can give convert a third argument to replace them (as they are not allowed in an Array), e.g. `convert(Array, iris[1:3], 0.)`.

Comment: With Julia 1.0, it now prompts to change it to `convert(Matrix,` instead of `convert(Array,`.

Answer (score 10):

The accepted answer does a good job of answering the question as stated.

If your only reason for wanting to convert the DataFrame to an Array is to filter it, though, it may be worth looking into the methods available for filtering DataFrame objects directly. See, for some examples, https://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/subsets.html and https://dataframesjl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/split_apply_combine.html.

(Sorry in advance if this is better suited for a comment than an answer—not enough reputation to comment on here yet.)

Answer (score 8):

An update on the `convert` method, now, `convert(::Type{Array}, df::AbstractDataFrame)` is deprecated in favor of:

```
using DataFrames
convert(Matrix, df)
```

Which is equivalent to `Matrix(df)`

Answer (score 6):

This doesn't work in Julia 0.7 and above. Instead, try `Matrix(df)` and check out the tutorial [here](https://github.com/bkamins/Julia-DataFrames-Tutorial/blob/e2f78da6635231e8b1d0c397d6b8d5e57b887804/01_constructors.ipynb).

Answer (score 2):

The former solution does not work try Matrix(df,[:,1:3])